# Woocommerce: Add to cart shortcode without price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a WordPress developer and using WooCommerce for my e-commerce website.

When I use this shortcode: `[add_to_cart id="99"]`

I get something similar to this: `$50  Add to Cart`.

Can I add this button without a price?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the shortcode

```
[add_to_cart id="99" show_price="false"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must hook a function to the filter **woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' ); 

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Reference: WooCommerce Help Docs [click here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/)

Comment: Sorry @gmosornoza I don't know how to do that, I mean hook a function to the filter.

Comment: I paste these codes to function.php It's change button text of my single product view page only. The question is I want to remove price from shortcode add to cart button?

Comment: @Husnain i just updated the answer.  Let me know if that works